# Meaning of folder with right and left arrows in Aptana perspective

Tags: aptana

I have several folders in the Aptana perspective for a project. Most have the usual orange cylinder overlaid in the lower, right corner. But one has instead blue arrows, a right-pointing one and below it a left-pointing one. I don't know what this means or how it happened. Can anyone point me to the place in the Aptana documentation that will explain it and how I get things back to "normal"? I've searched, but no success. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Those icons are typically used for version control, like CVS or SVN. You might have accidentally switched to the [Team Synchronizing perspective](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-115.htm).

- A cylinder indicates that your local files are in sync with the main repository.
- A right-pointing blue arrow indicates that there are *outgoing changes* for that folder: you have edited a file contained in that folder, but you haven't committed those changes yet.
- A left-pointing arrow means that there are *incoming changes* for that folder. As you can probably infer, that means that someone else has committed changes, which you have not yet checked out.

For a whole lot more information, see [this tutorial](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-the-team-synchronizing-perspective-in-eclipse.html) (which might be out of date, but it shows the right screenshots).